# How can I write to a file one byte at a time from int? C++

Tags: c++, int, output, byte

I'm writing to a file one byte at a time in C++. So far I have a code like this:

```
if ( i == 0 ) { outputfile << '\x0';}
if ( i == 1 ) { outputfile << '\x1';}
....
if ( i == 254 ) { outputfile << '\xfe';}
if ( i == 255 ) { outputfile << '\xff';}
```

It works but as you can imagine that's an extra 255 lines. If I were using Python it would be as simple as:

```
output.write(bytes((i,)))
```

Is there a simpler way to write single byte integers into bytes? Like a couples lines of code at most?

I've tried using char and some conversions for the past day but I'm not good at handling that data type at all. The file I write ends up having being corrupted. Even though the I get the file size right it takes up more size on disk that it should when I try that way.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Writing one byte at a time is a waste of efficiency.  Put them into a buffer, then block write the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

In every line, you are simply converting the int `i` to a `char`.

This matches the logic of all your code.

```
outputfile << static_cast<char>(i);
```

**However**, you likely don't want the text formatting that `operator <<` uses and should instead write:

```
outputfile.put( static_cast<char>(i) );
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried outputfile << However outputfile.put doesn't work either, It yields the same result.

Comment: @Enobeus sorry, I do not understand the meaning of your comment.

Comment: .put still gives me the same problem. Both << and put work with a file that's a few bytes big but when dealing with kilobytes, only the original code works. Sadly dealing with it 4 bytes at a time isn't an option either.

Comment: @Enobeus you're going to have to add an example of what you tried, what you expected and what you received because this should answer the question as you asked it. Which means you're asking something else and no one here is sure exactly what.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of those `if` statements. simply print out `(char) i`.

When you place a data type (like char, int, double, float) in parenthesis before a variable, this will convert that variable to the type.

`(int) 'a'` will convert the character 'a' to an integer of value 97.

`(char) 97` will convert the integer 97 to the character 'a'.

There's all kinds of things you can do with type casting, and you should be aware of possible overflows, but I'll leave this as something for you to research.

Comment: Thanks. I've used this before too. it's the same as outputfile << static_cast<char>(i);.I don't get type casting and spent the last day trying to understand it and getting it to work. it just doesn't. At least, not when the file size is kbs.